# Flutter - run/debug desktop app directly from Android Studio [configuration]

Tags: android-studio, debugging, flutter, desktop-application

I want to conveniently develop **Desktop** applications using **Flutter** & **Android Studio**. Currently Flutter Desktop Apps run only on the `master` channel.

I'm able to flawlessly enable MacOS as a flutter device with `export ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true` where my macos laptop shows as the following device:

```
$ flutter devices
1 connected device:

macOS • macOS • darwin-x64 • Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132
```

I can launch the app directly on desktop with `flutter run`

Which **Run/Debug configuration should I choose** to automatically build & launch Flutter app from Android Studio?

*Flutter ver. Channel master, v1.9.8-pre.108*

EDIT: as @smorgan correctly suggested, just run: 
`flutter config --enable-macos-desktop`

[image]
Remember that you also need to have macos build target in your app workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP`; any instructions referencing it are out of date. You should instead run `flutter config --enable-macos-desktop` as described [in the official documentation](https://flutter.dev/desktop#tooling).

That approach will enable desktop support everywhere, including Android Studio, rather than just the current terminal. Once you do that, normal Flutter workflows in Android Studio will work for desktop.

Comment: Thanks, running `flutter config --enable-macos-desktop` and restarting Android Studio is enough to develop for desktop supposing that the project already has macos build target.

Comment: Running `flutter create .` after `flutter config --enable-...-desktop` fixed it for me.